# findTransactionObjects returning an empty array when searching for a valid bundle hash

Tags: iri-legacy-api

I'm doing this, which returns an empty array:

```
    const iota = new IOTA({
    provider: 'http://node05.iotatoken.nl:16265'
});

iota.api.getNodeInfo(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        var hash = 'ACFYAZFUOS9HHAUAIDBXMVKKBUXVCPGQZNTVHXUHPEKDLHDDTEEHRGPXEBXSMHMEKFNNZOBBIAAMA9999';
        iota.api.findTransactionObjects({bundles:[hash] }, (err, res) =>{
!err && console.log(res);
err && console.log(err);
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the hash you pass is actually transaction hash:
[ACFYAZFUOS9HHAUAIDBXMVKKBUXVCPGQZNTVHXUHPEKDLHDDTEEHRGPXEBXSMHMEKFNNZOBBIAAMA9999](https://thetangle.org/transaction/ACFYAZFUOS9HHAUAIDBXMVKKBUXVCPGQZNTVHXUHPEKDLHDDTEEHRGPXEBXSMHMEKFNNZOBBIAAMA9999)

If you want to find transaction by bundle hash, you should enter this instead:
[OCAKGAAGVPGLALQJRWVIAKR9PDNDGQOXUGAISTUHFDZLHEIQQKHNKLVDX9CIFJVBXQFDZHIQVFWEGNIHW](https://thetangle.org/bundle/OCAKGAAGVPGLALQJRWVIAKR9PDNDGQOXUGAISTUHFDZLHEIQQKHNKLVDX9CIFJVBXQFDZHIQVFWEGNIHW)